# Improper integral $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\left \{ x \right \}-\frac{1}{2}}{x(\log x+z)}dx$

Tags: limits, improper-integrals, special-functions, summation-by-parts

We have the integral : 
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\left \{ x \right \}-\frac{1}{2}}{x(\log x+z)}dx$$
$\left \{ x \right \}=$ fractional part of $x$, and $z$ is a complex variable whose real part is strictly positive. 
By the well-known summation formula : 
$$\sum_{a<n\leq b}f(n)=\int_{a}^{b}\left(f(x)+f^{'}(x)\left[\left \{ x \right \}-\frac{1}{2}\right]\right)dx+\frac{f(b)}{2}-\frac{f(a)}{2};\;\;\;\;\ a,b \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$$
We have:
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\left \{ x \right \}-\frac{1}{2}}{x(\log x+z)}dx=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=2}^{N}\log(\log(n)+z)+\frac{3}{2}\log(z)-e^{-z}\text{Ei}(z)+e^{-z}\text{Ei}\left(\log N+z\right)-\left(N+\frac{1}{2}\right)\log(\log N+z)$$
Where $\text{Ei}(\cdot)$ is the exponential integral function.

Now, we have:
$$\sum_{n=2}^{N}\log(\log(n)+z)=\sum_{n=2}^{N}\log\log(n)+\sum_{n=2}^{N}\log\left(1+\frac{z}{\log n}\right)$$
Using similar arguments, we also have 
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n=2}^{N}\log\log(n)-\left(N+\frac{1}{2}\right)\log\log N +\text{li}(N)=k(=\text{constant})$$
Where $\text{li}(\cdot)$ is the logarithmic integral function.

Thus :
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\left \{ x \right \}-\frac{1}{2}}{x(\log x+z)}dx=k+\frac{3}{2}\log(z)-e^{-z}\text{Ei}(z)+\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n=2}^{N}\log\left(1+\frac{z}{\log n}\right)+e^{-z}\text{Ei}\left(\log N+z\right)-\text{li}(N)+\left(N+\frac{1}{2}\right)\log\left(\frac{\log N}{z+\log N}\right)$$

My Idea to make the log-summation converge is to complement it with a sequence $a_{n}(z)$ such that :

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\log\left(1+\frac{z}{\log n}\right)-a_{n}(z)$$ is convergent as well as:

$$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}e^{-z}\text{Ei}\left(\log N+z\right)-\text{li}(N)+\left(N+\frac{1}{2}\right)\log\left(\frac{\log N}{z+\log N}\right)+\sum_{n=2}^{N}a_{n}(z)$$
What is the sequence $a_{n}(z)$ ?

Comment: expanding $f_s(z)=\int_1^\infty x^{-s-1} \frac{\{x\}-\frac{1}{2}}{\ln x+z}dx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-z)^{-k}\int_1^\infty x^{-s-1} \ln^k(x) (\{x\}-\frac12)dx$ $= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-z)^{-k}\frac{d^k}{ds^k} (\frac{\zeta(s)}{-s}+\frac{1}{s-1})$ I find $f_0(z)=\int_{|u|=\epsilon}(\frac{\zeta(u)}{-u}+\frac{1}{u-1})u^{-1}\exp(\frac{-1}{zu})du$

Comment: I believe that there is a typo in your first identitty @user1952009 since $$\frac{1}{\log x+z}=\frac{1}{z}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \left(\frac{\log x}{z}\right)^k.$$ And why do you know that this geometric series does converge?

Comment: The last integral converges, so there are some chances it gives your integral. Anyway it was fun to write.